# Calico network policy in Kubernetes based on Domain name & Wildcard char

Tags: kubernetes, calico

I have an application running with kubernetes orchestrator. I want to implement calico network policy based on domain name or wildcard characters so that domain names (`FQDN`/`DNS`) can be used to allow access from a pod or set of pods (via label selector).

I came across [calico doc](https://docs.projectcalico.org/security/calico-enterprise/egress-access-controls#egress-access-control-to-external-endpoints) which says the same thing, but not sure if this is free or paid ? Can someone confirm this? also where I can get example of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DNS policy** is a paid feature since it's a part of Calico Enterprise and Calico  Cloud. You can check this [here](https://www.tigera.io/features/dns-policy/).

[Full comparison of features between open source calico, cloud and enterprise](https://www.tigera.io/tigera-products/)

As for examples, it's often very difficult to find working examples for paid products, however I managed to find simple example of how it will look like:

```
apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: GlobalNetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: security.allow-external-dns-egress
spec:
  tier: security
  selector: 'projectcalico.org/namespace == "dev" && app == "centos"'
  order: 90
  types:
    - Egress
  egress:
  - action: Allow
    protocol: UDP
    source: {}
    destination:
      ports:
      - '53'
      # openshift dns port
      - '5353'
  - action: Allow
    source:
      selector: app == 'centos'
    destination:
      domains:
      - '*.google.com'
      - 'google.com'
  # this rule only necessary if there is no policy that would pass all unmatched traffic to the following tier
  # - action: Pass
  #   source: {}
  #   destination: {}
```

[Link to this example above in Calico github](https://github.com/tigera-solutions/calico-security-controls-for-k8s/blob/master/demo/50-dns-policy/calico.allow-external-dns-egress.yaml)

Idea is to not allow any egress traffic to any domains, but google.com

It's shown how it should work in the [example](https://github.com/tigera-solutions/calico-security-controls-for-k8s#dns-policy).

Comment: will this example work since it is under enterprise package? I want to implement network policy based on domain using CIDR, you think Kubernetes DNSSelector  [ https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/50453 ] might help ?

Comment: This will work if you use calico enterprise, there are no other options to have this work like this. Also for the last state they suggested using `calico cni` for this - see [this comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/50453#issuecomment-368334028)

Comment: How about Kubernetes DNS service https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/ to control the egress calls ? With some dns server that I can integrate with k3s and use this service ?

Comment: This is a different question and you should consider asking this separately to comply with StackExchange guidelines. Please refer to [One post with multiple questions or multiple posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts)